# Fountain_v11(RenderScript) failed on Android 4.3

Tags: android, renderscript, android-4.3-jelly-bean

Recently , I rebuild fountain_v11 renderscript test apk, and found it cannot run on Android 4.3 platform.

It always crash in function root() in file Fountain.rs.

This will crash:

```
        if ((p->position.y > height) && (p->delta.y > 0)) {
        p->delta.y *= -0.3f;
    }
```

I am not sure why this operation is illegal?

Is there someone who can help me?

Thanks

Comment: Are you compiling with the 4.3 SDK? What device are you attempting to run this on (and what version of Android is it running)?

Comment: Yes, I am compiling with 4.3 SDK, and I found the error is caused by attribute, if I removed packed(1) from the attribute the apk can run correctly. Or add an meaningless variable such as char or float before the variable of delta in struct Point_t, it worked also. And the device I used is Sam Sung I9260

Comment: Right, you should probably remove the "packed" attribute permanently, since it can cause portability issues.

Comment: Do you know why? Since with 4.2 SDK, the packed attribute is there and can ran correctly. But after move to 4.3 SDK, is the problem with RS complier, also I haven't any clue from git of RS. thanks